# Google Drive for Desktop stopped streaming my local folder

Tags: google-drive

Due to an unknown reason, my Google account was disconnected from the Google Drive desktop app and I had to re-sign in. Since having done that, my Google Drive folder (the one that was designated as the streaming location) became disconnected from Google Drive and the streaming location has been changed to a virtual drive letter instead. when I attempted to change the streaming location back to the old folder in the app's settings, it failed because "The selected folder must be empty", and that folder is obviously not empty, since it used to be the streaming location until not so long ago.

I noticed that the icon of my old Google Drive folder indicates that it is known by Google Drive, but not synced:

[image: Google Drive folder icon]

How do I configure Google Drive to use my old folder as streaming location?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method, I already successful to sync my file:

Click the google drive icon on the taskbar => setting icon => Preferences => Select tab "Google Drive" => Tick "Mirror Files" option => Choose the old folder of Google Drive on local file. Then Google Drive will fetching all the items.

Wait and happy ^^